# Sylius : Wrong total order amount passed to Stripe

Tags: symfony, stripe-payments, sylius

I added a new processor allowing to calculate the amount of the gift card.

```html
services:
    app.order_processing.gift_card_processor:
        class: App\OrderProcessing\GiftCardProcessor
        arguments:
            - '@sylius.factory.adjustment'
            - '@translator'
        tags:
            - { name: sylius.order_processor, priority: 5 }
```

```html
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\OrderProcessing;

use App\Entity\Order\Adjustment;
use App\Entity\Order\Order;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Model\OrderInterface as BaseOrderInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Processor\OrderProcessorInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Resource\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Webmozart\Assert\Assert;

final class GiftCardProcessor implements OrderProcessorInterface
{
    private FactoryInterface $adjustmentFactory;

    private TranslatorInterface $translator;

    public function __construct(
        FactoryInterface $adjustmentFactory,
        TranslatorInterface $translator
    ) {
        $this->adjustmentFactory = $adjustmentFactory;
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function process(BaseOrderInterface $order): void
    {
        /** @var Order $order */
        Assert::isInstanceOf($order, Order::class);

        // Remove all gift card adjustments, we recalculate everything from scratch.
        $order->removeAdjustments(Adjustment::ORDER_GIFT_CARD_ADJUSTMENT);

        foreach ($order->getGiftCardOrders() as $giftCardOrder) {
            $giftCard = $giftCardOrder->getGiftCard();
            $giftCardRemainingAmount = (int) $giftCard->getRemainingAmount() * 100;

            $amount = $giftCardRemainingAmount > $order->getTotal() ? $order->getTotal() : $giftCardRemainingAmount;

            /** @var Adjustment $adjustment */
            $adjustment = $this->adjustmentFactory->createNew();
            $adjustment->setType(Adjustment::ORDER_GIFT_CARD_ADJUSTMENT);
            $adjustment->setAmount(-$amount);
            $adjustment->setLabel($this->translator->trans('gift_card.ui.gift_card'));

            $giftCard->addAdjustment($adjustment);

            $giftCardOrder->setAmount($amount / 100);

            $order->addAdjustment($adjustment);
        }
    }
}
```

The total order amount displayed in the cart and inserted in the database is correct **(screenshot 1 and 2)**.

[SCREENSHOT 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxwf2.png)
[SCREENSHOT 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbElu.png)

The bug occurs during payment on stripe, the amount displayed corresponds to the initial amount which does not support the reduction of the gift card **(screenshot 3)**

[SCREENSHOT 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4FB1.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this Sylius plugin : `flux-se/sylius-payum-stripe-plugin` you have to create individual coupons representing your gift cards decorating : https://github.com/FLUX-SE/SyliusPayumStripePlugin/blob/master/src/Provider/DetailsProvider.php the new array member to create is the `discounts` like the Stripe doc is defining it : https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-discounts

The plugin is only taking care of default Sylius adjustments linked to an `OrderItem` or an `OrderItemUnit`. If the adjustment is linked on the `Order` then it won't be taken into account because Stripe is only making a sum of all `line_item` as total. Stripe is not allowing negative amount for a line item, that's why coupons are the only way to reduce the total amount of the payment.

Here is the required payum extension handling the creation of coupons if you label the coupon ids with this format `sprintf('GIFT_CARD_%s', $giftCard->getCode())` :

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\GiftCard\Payum\Extension;

use FluxSE\PayumStripe\Request\Api\Resource\CreateCoupon;
use FluxSE\PayumStripe\Request\Api\Resource\RetrieveCoupon;
use FluxSE\SyliusPayumStripePlugin\Action\ConvertPaymentAction;
use Payum\Core\Extension\Context;
use Payum\Core\Extension\ExtensionInterface;
use Payum\Core\Request\Convert;
use Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\PaymentInterface;

final class CheckCouponsExtension implements ExtensionInterface
{
    public function onPreExecute(Context $context)
    {
    }

    public function onExecute(Context $context)
    {
    }

    public function onPostExecute(Context $context)
    {
        if ($context->getException()) {
            return;
        }

        if (false === $context->getAction() instanceof ConvertPaymentAction) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var mixed|Convert $request */
        $request = $context->getRequest();
        if (false === $request instanceof Convert) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var mixed|PaymentInterface $payment */
        $payment = $request->getSource();
        if (false === $payment instanceof PaymentInterface) {
            return;
        }

        $order = $payment->getOrder();
        if (null === $order) {
            return;
        }

        $gateway = $context->getGateway();
        foreach ($order->getGiftCardOrders() as $giftCardOrder) {
            $giftCard = $giftCardOrder->getGiftCard();
            $couponId = sprintf('GIFT_CARD_%s', $giftCard->getCode());
            $retrieveCouponRequest = new RetrieveCoupon($couponId);
            try {
                $gateway->execute($retrieveCouponRequest);
            } catch (ApiErrorException $e) {
                $createCouponRequest = new CreateCoupon([
                    'id' => $couponId,
                    "amount_off" => $giftCard->getAmount()/100,
                    "currency" => $order->getCurrencyCode(),
                    "metadata" => [
                        'SYLIUS_GIFTCARD_ID' => $giftCard->getId(),
                        'SYLIUS_GIFTCARD_CODE' => $giftCard->getCode(),
                    ],
                    "name" => sprintf("Gift card #%d", $giftCard->getId()),
                ]);
                $gateway->execute($createCouponRequest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the service declaration :

```yaml
services:
  App\GiftCard\Payum\Extension\CheckCouponsExtension:
    public: true
    tags:
      - name: payum.extension
        alias: app.extension.check_coupons
        factory: stripe_checkout_session
```

Comment: this will create a coupon on the stripe coupons dashboard? or it creates a coupon on the Sylius part?

Comment: It creates a Stripe Coupon, on the Sylius part a gift card were created on the order during the checkout thanks to the gift card plugin.